# Django tutorial throws ImportError if importing the model from commandline python

Tags: django, django-models

Given the exact code from the tutorial part [Creating models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/#id2)

**polls/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Why can't I `from .models import Question`?

```bash
[polls]$ python
Python 3.8.12 (default, Dec  4 2021, 10:54:00) 
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from .models import Question
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Otherweise the tutorial works fine so yes **_*init*_.py** exists in the **polls** directory (created by the django tutorial). None of the many related questions have helped me, thus please don't close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from polls.models import Question`, because it depends on what's your current directory when using relative import.
If you were in correct directory, use django command `./manage.py shell` to test your trial, it should work because `./manage.py shell` is compaitable with your current django project settings.

Comment: I'm already in the directory `polls`

Comment: I guess python shell cannot use your current django project config, so use terminal command `./manage.py shell` to solve this issue.